# Python (1..n) syntax?

Tags: python, sage

I see in the code on this [Sage wiki page](http://wiki.sagemath.org/interact) the following code:

```
@interact
def _(order=(1..12)):
```

Is this `(1..n)` syntax unique to Sage or is it something in Python? Also, what does it do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's Sage-specific. You can use `preparse` to see how it is desugared to:

```
sage: preparse("(1..12)")
'(ellipsis_iter(Integer(1),Ellipsis,Integer(12)))'
```

See [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/misc/misc.html#sage.misc.misc.ellipsis_iter) for documentation of `ellipsis_iter`, [here](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/misc/preparser.html) for information on the preparser.

Answer (score 10):

There was a Python PEP to add this notation to Python, but it was rejected.  Robert Bradshaw decided to implement it anyways, but for the Sage preparser.  He implemented the following:

- (a..b)   -- like xrange, so an iterator
- [a..b]   -- list, including endpoints
- [a,b,..,c]  -- arithmetic progression

Answer (score 1):

This is not Python syntax. I would guess that it creates a range from 1 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

`(1..n)` syntax does not exist in Python.