# How to make Python treat sequences as 1-indexed instead of 0-indexed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example:
 My code:

```
lst=[15,18,20,1,19,65]
print(lst[2])
```

It prints 20, but I want my array to be 1-indexed and print 18 instead.

```
98,67,86,3,4,21
```

When I print the second number it should print 67 and not 86 based on indexing.
First number is 98
Second number is 67
Third number is 86 and so on. How to make my program have index 0 become index 1 and so on?

Comment: When you wrote "it prints 2", did you mean "it prints 20"?

Comment: "I want my program to count index 0 as first element, index 1 as second element and so on." - that's exactly what Python does!?

Comment: Just pass index -1 everywhere ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry typing mistake@DaveCosta

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239668/python-sage-can-lists-start-at-index-1  
same question here.

Comment: Array is always starting with `0` no matter what (not the value but indexing)

Comment: why do you want to do this? I don't think you should try to change this. Starting from 0 is a fundamental feature of python

Comment: ... of programming in general basically...

Comment: If you want you can always subtract 1 from the index or even go the further step and implement your own class extending `list` with your own indexing system. But for built-in list this is what it is...

Comment: You could also just try inserting a dummy element at index 0, which is absolutely not good practice but will essentially achieve what you're trying to do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be done, Python's `list` and every other sequence is inherently 0-indexed. The same is true for the vast majority of modern programming languages. I would suggest you to just learn to live with it, it will not be the hardest thing in your programming career.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 1 from the index you are actually trying to look up.

```
print(lst[2-1])
```