# Change numpy array indexes (not values)

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array, and i want see if it's possible to modify the index values (not the array values) with a custom sequence of numbers.

Let's say the array lengh is 10, it's possible to change the indexes so instead of accessing it's elements with the indexes `0-9` it can be accesed with.. let's say.. `50-59`?

Basically like changing the `rownames/colnames` but in a np array instead of a pandas df.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/10378515/15032126, I would expect the same for numpy arrays.

Comment: `numpy` arrays don't have row/col names.  Indices are strictly by count starting with 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is ever a need for it and I'm sure there are other ways but one way would be to create a class for it. Working on your example of 50-59:

```
class UnnaturalList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if type(index) == int and index > 0:
            index -= 50
        if type(index) == slice:
            start, stop = index.start, index.stop
            if start and start > 0:
                start -= 50
            if stop and stop > 0:
                stop -= 50
            index = slice(start, stop, index.step)
        return super().__getitem__(index)

    def __setitem__(self, index, val):
        super().__setitem__(index - 50, val)
```

Then you can create a list with this class and use indexing and slicing

```
a_list = UnnaturalList(range(1,6))
a_list --> [1,2,3,4,5]
a_list[50] --> 1
a_list[51] --> 2
a_list[50:53] --> [1,2,3]
```

I would think there is a way to do something similar for arrays, or something cleaner, but this is one method for you.

Comment: Yeah, i saw the linked question up there and it seems wrapping it into another class is the only way. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Sorry wrong post